# Excluding camera tracked video from Final render (while keeping tracking Data)

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes, transparency, tracking

[image][image]GOAL - To track a source video to get the tracking data while excluding the actual video in the final Render.

INFO

I've tracked the video, but it is just the base video and I have an edited video in After Effects that I want to apply the effects from Blender onto. I tracked this source video expecting to be able to create my effect (ember particles) with the video as a reference not a final product. I can't seem to find a way to disable the video in my motion tracked scene during my final render. I'm not sure if I should try getting rid of the video or extracting the camera data and putting it into a new scene.

Comment: That is very easy, just disconnect the movie node from the original movie and use an other one with the new one. To help you better please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add an image that shows your current render nodes.

Comment: That sounds like that would work if I was planning to have the finished shot in blender, but I want the finished shot to be done in After Effects. If I remove the video can I just leave it blank to get a transparent background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not make a new scene, you do need the tracking information.

Basically what you don't need  is the video to be part of the compositing.

But since you are using undistortion you need to distort your output so that it matches the original footage. (Use the undistort node but change its function to **distort** and set it to use the information from the original tracked video clip)

[image]

The rest is easy, just render your particles using a transparent background (film transparent https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR1He.png)

Render as image sequence in OpenEXR format.

Then bring the rendered image sequence into the compositing software you will use to finish the shot.

Comment: Im not sure I understand how to do this. I switched the distortion to distort and toggled on transparency and nothing changed. Could ya give me a step by step perhaps?

Comment: I have no clue how you set up your scene or your render layers. You just need the output of the layer that has your particles using transparency. Then save that as EXR.

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/3STqy77jG50 .  So I should be trying to get rid of the video? when I try to disconnect the vid I get an all white render. But yea I'll keep messing with it. thanks!

Comment: Start by setting your nodes like the image above. The render layer should be the one that holds your particles.

Comment: Alright cool so now it's rendering, but its just like the alpha. I'll add a picture. I can work with that, but I should probably know the proper way to do it. How can I get my full scene to render from here?

Comment: How did you render that? Did you render as EXR?

Comment: Ah ha! Success! I believe you guys have solved my problem once again. So I assume this still contains the tracking data even though I deleted all the nodes except the ones you said.